# cin and buffer problem

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

Hi I have question regarding cin and buffer.
I want to make a simple io program which takes integers.

Anyway I stumbled to a problem with buffer. Using MinGW in windows7 the following code will print out all four integers that I input. But when I switch to SunOS and compile it with G++ it will only print out the first integer. Is this a compiler issue or is it a operating system issue?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i;

   cout << "Enter four integers: ";
   cin >> i;
   cout << "\nYou entered the numbers: " << i << " ";

   cin >> i; cout << " ";
   cin >> i; cout << " ";
   cin >> i; cout << " ";

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should print out the first number on pretty any system.

```
cout << " ";
```

versus

```
cout << " " << i;
```

Therefore many guidelines state to do only one operation per line. The cin just optically clutters the reading. Actually you never output `i` excepted the first time.

Comment: ah, true.. I didn't see that one ^^;

Comment: No problem, I think you probably reformatted the code to figure out where the problem was. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In these lines:

```
cin >> i; cout << " ";
cin >> i; cout << " ";
cin >> i; cout << " ";
```

...you're reading a number (if possible) but then just printing out a space, *not* the number you just read. If you really need to do this, I'd probably write a small function, and use it:

```
int get_input() { 
    int ret;
    cin >> ret;
    cout << ret;
    return ret;
}

// ...
cout << "Enter four integers: ";

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    get_input();
```

I can't say I'm particularly excited about that function, but under the circumstances, it's probably at least a little better than nothing (just not *much* better).